# Recursively remove folders generated by Heat.exe with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion, wix, heat

I know there are questions and answers out there for removing single directories.  I have an XML generated by Heat.exe that contains 1000s of files and about 20 top level directories.  I want to use the xsl transform to remove one of those top level directories.  That directory has 6 directories in it and those directories have some etc.

I have code that will either remove just the top level directory (called tests) and any subfolders that do not have subfolders themselves, leaving me with unresolved reference errors:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

        <!-- Copy all attributes and elements to the output. -->
        <xsl:template match="@*|*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

        <!-- Create searches for the directories to remove. -->
     <xsl:key name="tests-search" match="wix:Directory[@Name='tests']//wix:Component" use="@Id" />
<!-- Remove directories. -->
    <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='tests']" />
<!-- Remove Components referencing those directories. -->
 <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('tests-search', @Directory)]" />
  <!-- Remove DirectoryRefs (and their parent Fragments) referencing those directories. -->
<xsl:template match="wix:Fragment[wix:DirectoryRef[key('tests-search', @Id)]]" />
```

If I change the key line to be

```html
<xsl:key name="tests-search1" match="wix:Directory[@Name = 'tests']" use="descendant::wix:Component/@Id" />
```

It will remove all subfolder their subfolders, but leave the all the Components (files) that are in the top level directory.

If I use both keys, it still ends with all components in the top level directory (tests) existing, giving me Unresolved reference errors.

Is there a way or a single search key to use that will remove all files and subfolders from a top level folder recursively?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/functions/expath-file/delete.html